# how to concatenate records only when record two matches a pattern

Tags: regex, join, awk, matching

I have a file consisting of time stamps and dropped packet information:

```
Tue May 13 09:50:00 HST 2014
Tue May 13 09:55:00 HST 2014
60 packets transmitted, 50 packets received, 16.7% packet loss
Tue May 13 10:00:00 HST 2014
60 packets transmitted, 54 packets received, 10.0% packet loss
Tue May 13 10:05:00 HST 2014
Tue May 13 10:10:00 HST 2014
Tue May 13 10:15:00 HST 2014
```

Using awk, I want to output, only the packet information line, joined with the date line immediately preceding it:

```
Tue May 13 09:55:00 HST 2014 60 packets transmitted, 50 packets received, 16.7% packet loss
Tue May 13 10:00:00 HST 2014 60 packets transmitted, 54 packets received, 10.0% packet loss
```

I cant find any information on joining records based on pattern matching. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `sed`,

```
sed -n 'N; /packet/s/\n/ /p; D;' yourfile
```

Comment: Nice solution! I hadn't considered sed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '/loss$/ {print p,$0} {p=$0}' file
Tue May 13 09:55:00 HST 2014 60 packets transmitted, 50 packets received, 16.7% packet loss
Tue May 13 10:00:00 HST 2014 60 packets transmitted, 54 packets received, 10.0% packet loss
```